# Bootstrap table formatting wrong in Chrome but correct in Firefox

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table which is formatted completely correctly in Firefox but is all thrown to the right on Chrome. Any ideas?

Firefox:

[image: The first column, which only has a checkbox, is narrow.]

Chrome:

[image: The first column is very wide, pushing all other columns to the right.]

I originally thought it might be something to do with it being within a table-responsive div but I removed that and it made no difference.

!----- UPDATE -----!

It appears to be the column sizing. If i remove that then the formatting goes back to normal but I can't control the table column sizes.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th class="col-1 text-center"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="option1"></th>
          <th class="col-2"><a class="text-body" href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=displayName">Name</a></th>
          <th class="col-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body" href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=companyName">Organisation</a></th>
          <th class="col-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body" href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=jobTitle">Job Title</a></th>
          <th class="col-1 d-none d-md-table-cell"><a class="text-body" href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=profession">NSO</a></th>
          <th class="col-1 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body" href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=lastModifiedDateTime">Last Updated</a></th>
          <th class="col-1">Profile</th>
        </tr>
        {% if contacts %}
        {% for contact in contacts %}
        <tr>
          <td class="col-1 text-center"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" name='selected_contact' value={{ contact.per_contact_id }}></td>
          <td class="col-2"><a href="mailto:?bcc={{ contact.emailAddresses.0.address }}" class="text-primary">{{ contact.displayName }}</a></td>
          <td class="col-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.companyName }}</td>
          <td class="col-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.jobTitle }}</td>
          <td class="col-1 d-none d-md-table-cell">{{ contact.profession }}</a></td>
          <td class="col-1 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.modified }}</td>
          <td class="col-1"><button name="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-success noline" value={{ contact.per_contact_id }}>View</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BSMP says, it looks like chrome doesn't play well when you add col classes to tables. So I just used a bit of custom css instead:

```
.w5 {
    width: 5%;
}
.w10 {
    width: 10%;
}
.w15 {
    width: 15%;
}
.w20 {
    width: 20%;
}
.w25 {
    width: 25%;
}
.w30 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the documentation for version 4 but nothing in the [Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/) or [Table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/) section suggests that you can use the layout classes in table cells the way you are here. In particular, the `flex` property isn't working on the table cells.

The first column is super wide in Chrome because all of the `col-*` classes have a width of 100%. In Chrome, this causes the first column to attempt to take up 100% of the space so it ends up being very wide and forcing the other columns to be narrow.

Consider adding to [Bootstrap's existing width classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/) rather than trying to size the column with layout classes:

```css
.w-8 {
  width: 8.333%;
}

.w-16 {
  width: 16.667;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center w-8"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="option1"></th>
      <th class="w-16">Name</th>
      <th class="w-25 d-none d-lg-table-cell">Organization</th>
      <th class="w-25 d-none d-lg-table-cell">Job Title</th>
      <th class="w-8 d-none d-md-table-cell">NSO</th>
      <th class="w-8 d-none d-lg-table-cell">Last Updated</th>
      <th class="w-8">Profile</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
          <td class="text-center w-8"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" name='selected_contact' value=""></td>
          <td class="w-16"><a href="mailto:" class="text-primary">Example Name</a></td>
          <td class="w-25 d-none d-lg-table-cell">Example Company</td>
          <td class="w-25 d-none d-lg-table-cell">Example Title</td>
          <td class="w-8 d-none d-md-table-cell">Example Profession</a></td>
          <td class="w-8 d-none d-lg-table-cell">MM/DD/YYY</td>
          <td class="w-8"><button name="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-success noline" value="">View</button></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Create the `w-8` and `w-16` classes, use them and the existing `w-25` class to replace the `col-*` classes in your table. I made a runnable version without the Django code so you could see it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code have some change, you forgot to add `row` class and `col-md-1` or`col-sm-1` etc in you column replace your code with following code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <table class="table">
            <thead>
               <tr class="row">
                  <th class="col-md-1 text-center"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
                        id="checkAll" value="option1"></th>
                  <th class="col-md-2"><a class="text-body"
                        href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=displayName">Name</a></th>
                  <th class="col-md-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body"
                        href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=companyName">Organisation</a></th>
                  <th class="col-md-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body"
                        href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=jobTitle">Job Title</a></th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 d-none d-md-table-cell"><a class="text-body"
                        href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=profession">NSO</a></th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 d-none d-lg-table-cell"><a class="text-body"
                        href="?page={{ contacts.number }}&order_by=lastModifiedDateTime">Last Updated</a></th>
                  <th class="col-md-1">Profile</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {% if contacts %}
               {% for contact in contacts %}
               <tr class="row">
                  <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
                        id="blankCheckbox" name='selected_contact' value={{ contact.per_contact_id }}></td>
                  <td class="col-md-2"><a href="mailto:?bcc={{ contact.emailAddresses.0.address }}"
                        class="text-primary">{{ contact.displayName }}</a></td>
                  <td class="col-md-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.companyName }}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.jobTitle }}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-1 d-none d-md-table-cell">{{ contact.profession }}</a></td>
                  <td class="col-md-1 d-none d-lg-table-cell">{{ contact.modified }}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-1"><button name="submit_button" type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-link text-success noline" value={{ contact.per_contact_id }}>View</button></td>
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}
               {% endif %}
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
```

if it work let me know